# is it portable to treat std::vector like array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I have seen people in my team writing code like this. I personally think this is not portable since vector could be implemented in a totally different way. Am I right?

```
vector<int> a;
a.push_back(1);
a.push_back(2);
a.push_back(3);

int* b = &a[0];
std::cout<< *(b +1); // this will print 2
```

Comment: In fact, as of 2011, there is the [`data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) member function for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @BoBTFish Since `data` has a `const` qualifier, `b` would need to be declared `const int* b`.

Comment: @Mark second that. Now let's all upvote the original question as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That code is correct. The elements stored in a `std::vector` are guaranteed to be stored contiguously as of C++03.

This is the relevant part of the current standard C++ draft `N3797` (23.3.6.1):

> A vector is a sequence container that supports random access
>   iterators. In addition, it supports (amortized) constant time insert
>   and erase operations at the end; insert and erase in the middle take
>   linear time. Storage management is handled automatically, though hints
>   can be given to improve efficiency. **The elements of a vector are
>   stored contiguously**, meaning that if v is a vector where T is some
>   type other than bool, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n`
>   for all `0 <= n < v.size()`.

Answer (score 8):

In whatever way a vector might be implemented, some things are guaranteed by the standard to remain consistent. A `std::vector` is always stored contiguously in memory and that is why it can work with random access iterators.